# Retrieving date from element into a string, then retrieving the year from the date

Tags: c#, xml

I have a method I wrote that extracts the date from a node thus:

```
strRemoveByDate = element.SelectSingleNode("Date_Removed").InnerText
```

which gives me "2012-01-01" or whatever the case may be.

Now I need to just grab the year. I tried using a substring, but it's not working:

```
String strYear = strRemoveByDate.Substring(0,4);
```

What do I need to do here?

EDIT:: Apologies to Mr. Skeet.  I do not want to come accross as rude. I appreciate any help I can get. By 'It's not working' I mean:

I try to parse just the four digits of the year from the string. Nothing happens. I go into the page I am working on in VS, add a quickwatch to the var strYear, and it says that 'strYear does not exist in this current context'. Nothing is being read into strYear.

EDIT 2: Turns out that there is something weird going on here....  I tried all of these solutions, none work (hold on... I'll elaborate).  Very strange behaviour. So in the method I'm writing, I put the declaration

```
String nonsenseString = "nonsense";
```

and the IDE isn't even picking that up. So..... it would seem that my overall problem is that I can't even declare a String, no matter how I try...

I have since closed and re-opened the page, shut down the IDE and restarted it, and shut down my workstation and restart it, too.

No avail.

Comment: "it's not working" is *never* enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: Apologies, I figured that MANY of the community members would be easily able to figure out what amounts to a fairly easy 'newbie' question.

Comment: Basically, if you want to get help, you should put in a reasonable amount of effort into making your question all that it can be. Just because a question is simple doesn't mean you shouldn't take the time to ask it well.

Comment: Lots of reasons why it's not working. For instance, all the smart people in the world might be on strike. Er, for wage equality...

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime getyear = DateTime.Parse(strRemoveByDate);
String strYear =getyear.year.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

`int year = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Year;`

Comment: @L.B Thanks - should be MM instead of mm

Comment: I'd also suggest using `InvariantCulture` rather than the current culture. I doubt that this is *really* culture-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String strYear = strRemoveByDate.Split('-')[0];
```

To split out the first part up to the `-`

Comment: Oh of course... Thank you... But why the heck doesn't substring work (fairly new to c#)?

Comment: @mrwienerdog: It's impossible to know why your existing code doesn't work when you won't tell us *in what way* it doesn't work.